# combine adjacent parallel lines

Tags: c#, emgucv

There is an image which only has vertical lines and horizontal lines. But there are some lines that are the same or they are close to each other, but they should be combined to only one line. Also I wrote loop to add line in a new list, the speed is slow. So I wonder if there are some efficient way for me to combine these adjacent lines to one line.

The following is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RecoverLine_list.Count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < RecoverLine_list.Count; j++) {
            for (int m = 0; m < RecoverLine_list.Count; m++) {

                if (RecoverLine_list[i] != RecoverLine_list[j] 
                 && RecoverLine_list[i] != RecoverLine_list[m] 
                 && RecoverLine_list[j] != RecoverLine_list[m]) {

                    if (RecoverLine_list[i].orientation == 0 
                     && RecoverLine_list[j].orientation == 0 
                     && RecoverLine_list[m].orientation == 0) {

                        if (Math.Abs(RecoverLine_list[i].P1.Y - RecoverLine_list[j].P1.Y) < 3 
                         && Math.Abs(RecoverLine_list[i].P1.Y - RecoverLine_list[m].P1.Y) < 3 
                         && Math.Abs(RecoverLine_list[j].P1.Y - RecoverLine_list[m].P1.Y) < 3) {
                            // define RecoverLine_list[i] as grid line
                            GridLine_list.Add(RecoverLine_list[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question? Your loop is O(n^3) because you have 3 loops nested. I'm not surprised it's slow.

Comment: What about separating horizontal lines and vertical lines to two lists, then sorting both lists? You could do your work in one pass then. Sorting is n*log(n) (much much faster)

Comment: Thanks for all your recommendation. I am new to Stack Overflow, and I am sorry I do not make the question eas for you to see. @firda I have do what you say formerly, but I get the wrong result because the number of lines do not reduce.

Comment: @MattBurland I know the three loop is the key problem, but I do not know how to write code that can deal with the problem efficiently. Do you have some advice?

Comment: Can you post your sorted-attempt? If you sort all lines by Y then you can do a for-loop looking at three lines, with absolutely same result.

Comment: @firda I cannot answer my own question now, so how can I show you my sorted attempt? Sorry I am new and I am not familiar with this.

Comment: @user3919259: Edit your question with your attempt.

Comment: You said my solution does not work. Didn't you? I don't know what you want to do, I have told you how to do, what you are already doing, faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(REWRITTEN)** So, assuming you want to somehow filter horizontal and vertical lines which are 'similar' and want both the code and good condition for what 'similar' should be, then here are my thoughts:

**First split horizontal and vertical lines:**

```
List<Line> vert = new List<Line>();
List<Line> horiz = new List<Line>();
foreach(Line ln in RecoverLine_list)
    if(ln.orientation == 0) horiz.Add(ln);
    else vert.Add(ln);
horiz.Sort(x, y => x.P1.Y.CompareTo(y.P1.Y));
vert.Sort(x, y => x.P1.X.CompareTo(y.P1.X));
```

or something like that (not exactly sure what your orientation is, I am just guessing including the coding of sorting using lambdas).

Then you can search the lines in one pass extracting good-ones:

```
List<Line> filtered = new List<Line>();
for(int i = 0; i < horiz.Count; i++) {
    filtered.Add(ln); // always add, we can skip next:
    if(i+1 >= horiz.Count) break;
    if(Math.Abs(horiz[i].P1.Y - horiz[i+1].P1.Y) <= 3)
    && Math.Abs(horiz[i].P1.X - horiz[i+1].P1.X) <= 3)
    && Math.Abs(horiz[i].P2.X - horiz[i+1].P2.X) <= 3))
        i++; // skip this line for being similar
}
```

but that is not final solution, because we can have lines close to each other in one coordinate but not in the other. So we need to add inner loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < horiz.Count-1; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < horiz.Count; j++) {
        if((horiz[j].P1.Y - horiz[i].P1.Y) > 3)
           break; // this one is too far, all next will be
        if(Math.Abs(horiz[i].P1.Y - horiz[j].P1.Y) <= 3)
        && Math.Abs(horiz[i].P1.X - horiz[j].P1.X) <= 3)
        && Math.Abs(horiz[i].P2.X - horiz[j].P2.X) <= 3))
            horiz.RemoveAt(j--); // skip this line for being similar
}}
```

Got the idea? Same for vertical lines.

Comment: I think I do the similiar work as yours. I set the threshold to be 3 and if Math.Abs(vert[i].P1.Y - vert[i+2].P1.Y)<3, I add the vert[i] to the GridLine_list.

Comment: I wrote code doing exactly the same thing. It looked like you want a speedup. I don't understand what you really want. Post some picture and mark lines you want to extract/join.

Comment: If you want different condition for joining them then describe it. You want to join lines with start and stop within 3px? abs(x.p1.x-y.p1.x)+abs(x.p1.y-y.p1.y) <= 3px? for p1 and p2? what do you want?

Comment: Great! Yes, I have gotten exactly what you mean, and my speed becomes faster. And also the problem you mention in the last is not serious for me because all my horizontal lines initialize from the same x position and end at the same x position, too.

Comment: There is another problem for me. There are some duplicate lines in the final horizontal linelist. And I to the list.Distinct code to remove them, but it does not work. Do you have some other methods? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hint for speedup - if you want to remove items in forward iteration, use either `LinkedList` or replace those items with nulls and create final list afterwards.

Comment: Did you add inner loop? That solves the multiple-duplicity problem as well.

Comment: Yes, I have do inner loop to remove the duplicity and I think it works. Thanks for your help. So kind of you!